# pgfplots: options for marks do not apply

Tags: pgfplots

I try to modify the marks but the options do not seem to change anything?!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Values.dat}
x y
1 1
2 3
3 3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
]
\addplot table [
    x=x, 
    y=y,
    only marks, % <-- no effect
    mark=o, % <-- no effect
    mark options={fill color=white,color = black} % <-- no effect
] 
{Values.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In this example I want white circles with a black border but I only get the standard mark.

[image]

Comment: Those options belong in `\addplot [<options>] table ...`, not `\addplot table [<options>] ...`.

Comment: ...great...thanks...shoudl I close or answer the question myself then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution**

Oh my god...my bad...thanks Jake for the hint.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Values.dat}
x y
1 1
2 3
3 3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
]
\addplot 
[ % <-- plot options
    only marks,
    mark=o,
    mark options={color = black}
] 
table 
[ % <-- table options
    x=x, 
    y=y,
] 
{Values.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]